# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un Activity a un Fragment ya existente?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Quisiera saber si se puede pasar datos de un Activity a un Fragmento cuando este ya existe (no crear uno nuevo).

**Por ejemplo:** Desde el Fragmento tengo un Botón Buscar el cual me abre un `Activity ListaClientes`, el cual me muestra un `ListView` en donde selecciono un Item, en el evento `setOnItemClickListener()` del `ListView` quiero mandar los datos del cliente a los `EditText` que tengo en el fragmento anterior, en este caso lo estoy mandando en duro, osea tengo mis `EditText` como `public static`, pero yo se que no es una correcta forma de enviar los datos, quisiera saber si hay alguna otra forma les dejo mis códigos.

**Fragmento:**

```
public class TomaPedido extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Button mBtnBuscarCliente;
    public static EditText mEtCodigo, mEtRazSoc, mEtNroDoc;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toma_pedido, container, false);

        mBtnBuscarCliente = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mBtnBuscarCliente);
        mEtCodigo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mEtCodigo);
        mEtRazSoc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mEtRazSoc);
        mEtNroDoc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mEtNroDoc);

        mBtnBuscarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListaClientes.class);
                intent.putExtra("p_codigo", mEtCodigo.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**ListaClientes (Activity):**

```
public class ListaClientes extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mLvClientes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_clientes);

        mLvClientes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mLvClientes);

        String p_codigo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("p_codigo");

        LLenaListView(p_codigo);

        mLvClientes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.mLvClientes) {
                    int codigo = ((CliPro) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getCodigo();
                    String razsoc = ((CliPro) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getRazsoc();
                    String nrodoc = ((CliPro) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getNrodoc();
                    TomaPedido.mEtCodigo.setText(String.valueOf(codigo));
                    TomaPedido.mEtRazSoc.setText(razsoc);
                    TomaPedido.mEtNroDoc.setText(nrodoc);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void LLenaListView(String p_codigo) {
        String parametros = "select_clipro.php?codigo=" + p_codigo;
        final String enlace = Helper.GRuta + parametros;

        Thread tListaClientes = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                final String context = HttpManager.getData(enlace);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (context == null) {
                            Crouton.makeText(ListaClientes.this, "Error en el servidor", Style.ALERT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        Helper.cliProArrayList = CliProJson.getClientes(context);
                        if (Helper.cliProArrayList == null) {
                            Crouton.makeText(ListaClientes.this, "Error en el servidor", Style.ALERT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        CliProArrayAdapter adapter = new CliProArrayAdapter(ListaClientes.this, Helper.cliProArrayList);
                        mLvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }
        };

        tListaClientes.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Has pensado en utilizar eventos? yo es lo que utilizo para enviar datos a una actividad existente. Lo único que tendrás que controlar el modificar los datos de una actividad desde otra, sino te dará una excepción

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es recomendable utilizar campos estáticos ya que puedes incurrir en problemas de concurrencia o leaks de memoria.

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

Desde el fragmento puedes llamar a la actividad utilizando `startActivityForResult()` de la siguiente manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListaClientes.class);
intent.putExtra("p_codigo", mEtCodigo.getText().toString());
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Entonces en la actividad asignas los valores que quieras devolver al fragmento

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
String razsoc = ((CliPro) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getRazsoc();
returnIntent.putExtra("razonSocial", razsoc);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

En cambio, si decides no retornar data entonces:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Por ultimo sobre escribes en el fragmento el metodo  `onActivityResult` de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String razsoc = data.getStringExtra("razonSocial");
            //Haces lo que necesites con la data, en este caso asignas los vales a los EditText

        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Aqui escribes el codigo para cuando decidas no devolver data
        }
    }
}
```